# Electrophilic substitution in phenyl alkyl ether

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, reactivity

> Phenylalkyl ethers undergo usual halogenation in the benzene ring, e.g., anisole undergoes bromination with bromine in ethanoic acid even in the absence of iron (III) bromide catalyst.

Why do we use ethanoic acid as a solvent? Why don't we use CS2 as a solvent? Does ethanoic acid has something to do in activating phenyl?

Comment: Fairly sure you can do it in nearly any solvent you like. And acetic acid is a ton cheaper than carbon disulfide.